# Ran into a URP sorting issue in Unity

Tags: unity-game-engine, 2d, urp

Apparently there is no way to access the transparency sort axis in code for Universal Render Pipeline's 2D Renderer data asset. I've looked at the Unity manual and have had no luck. I need to access this for my project due to camera rotation at runtime. If anyone knows of a workaround I could use the help.

I've tried using UnityEngine.Rendering namespace and using

```
GraphicsSettings.transparencySortMode = TransparencySortMode.CustomAxis;
GraphicsSettings.transparencySortAxis = new Vector3(-1f, 0f, 0f);
```

I've tried adding a camera to the code above to see if I could override the URP settings but no luck.